# Facebook for swift 4.2 implementation error

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0, swift4.2

Hi I am working on a project that requires Facebook login button to get our user login using facebook account. But the problem is that I am getting errors. It seems like the documentation is old and it is not working anyway. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/implement-the-sdk) it is for swift.

I have swift 4.2 for my project. And in my pod file I am using following dependencies

```
pod 'FacebookCore' 
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

**and in my AppDelegate following is my code**

```
import FacebookCore

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
  SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

and I am getting following error. No Matter how many time I have build my project and how many time I cleaned it

> **Error**: *Use of unresolved identifier 'SDKApplicationDelegate'*

Please tell me what is problem here?What I have to do here and what I am missing. If there is some good tutorial for swift please share me a link

Thanks

Comment: can you try a quick `pod update` just in case?

Comment: yes tried...... but I think this is old documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a recent project implementation FB login. Here it goes

In the Podfile
`pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'`

In the AppDelegate

```swift
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate
            .shared
            .application(application,
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        ...
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

            return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
}
```

---

## Edit 2019/10/29

Tested with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/implement-the-sdk

Podfile:

```
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
```

AppDelegate:

```swift
import UIKit
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        ...

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }
}
```

It seems that they made a mistake in the documentation and `SDKApplicationDelegate` must be renamed `ApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: as far as I remember since the Swift document wasn't working, I just use the obj-c one https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios to know what to do in swift

Comment: the link you shared and having the Obj C implementation

Comment: I updated my answer after testing the swift doc. Same as what I did before. It just seems a mistake in their doc

Comment: how to handle that application open url function already return GIDSignIn of google ?